# Check if winforms can be displayed on mono

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I am making a console application that displays some data in windows form popups primarily for development or to configure it. However, when deployed it is to be ran in a command line only environment, which will not be able to display the forms. I would like to know if there is a way to detect whether or not it is possible to display these forms so I can display the data in a different format or print an explanation if the data cannot be displayed (one of the forms is an image preview).

Answer (score 0):

Yes sir, i would like to give you two Methods, for the case "Mono":

This Checks, if your in Mono Runtime:

```
private Boolean IsMonoRuntime()
{
      return (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null);
}
```

This gives you the Mono-Version (Linux Package) or String.Empty:

```
    private String GetMonoRuntime()
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");

    if (type != null)
    {
        MethodInfo displayName = type.GetMethod("GetDisplayName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        if (displayName == null)
            return "Unix/Linux + Mono";
        else
            return "Unix/Linux + Mono " + displayName.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

I hope its whay ou needed.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm developing this applications on ubuntu, so it's always going to be using the mono runtime which can display winforms. What I need to check is whether or not the operating system has a GUI or is just command line in order to see if I can display the forms.